# Read ADC using DMA in STM32

Tags: stm32, dma, adc

I want to read ADC1 and ADC2 on an STM32 using DMA.
I use ADC callback as shown below:

```c
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{

}
```

How can I make a decision between ADC1 and ADC2?
For example, I want to update `Val_1` after ADC1 conversion is done and update `Val_2` after ADC2 conversion is done.

Comment: You can check which ADC is referenced in `hadc->Instance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc` passed into your callback function has an `Instance` field you can check. e.g.

```c
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    if (hadc->Instance == ADC1)
    {
        // ADC1 code
    }
    else if (hadc->Instance == ADC2)
    {
        // ADC2 code
    }
}
```